Is it possible to perform lattice attack on LCG equation?
I have been struggling with the following equation for sometime now and i feel like there is a mathematical way of solving it or even reduce the calculations from more than 65536 to something lower.
$k_i = (k_{i-1} + x_i)*CONST + 1   mod  2^{32}$
The first byte of $k_i$ is known and the first byte of $k_{i-1}$ is known also, while $x_i$ is a byte, the rest of the variables are 32 bits hence mod $2^{32}$.
The following code is doing 65536*2*2 calculations which is too much load and i need ways to improve it.
static void buildkey1list( )
/* Find all values for key1_12 that produce the correct MSB for key_11
 * See section 3.3 of the Biham-Kocher paper. */
{
uword   i, j, k, t;
uword   test, MSBi, MSBiminus1, temp, temp2;
byte    diff;

    MSBi       = key1list[12] & MSBMASK;
    MSBiminus1 = key1list[11] & MSBMASK;

    /* There's 2^24 possible values for key1_12, given its MSB.
     * We check them all, substitution multiplications by table-lookup and add
     * to save time */
    temp = (mulTab[MSB(MSBi)]<<24) - INVCONST;       /* = MULT(MSBi-1) */
    for( i = 0; i < 256; i++ )
    for( j = 0; j < 256; j++ )
    {
        temp2 = temp + (mulTab[i]<<16) + (mulTab[j]<<8);

        /* See the explanation in recursion1 how this works... */
        diff = MSB(MSBiminus1 - (temp2&MSBMASK));
        for( t=2; t; t--, diff-- ) for( k = 0; k < mTab2Counter[diff]; k++ )
        {
        test = temp2 + mulTab[mTab2[diff][k]] - MSBiminus1;
        if( test <= MAXDELTA )
        {
            key1list[12] = MSBi + (i<<16) + (j<<8) + mTab2[diff][k];
                    recursion1( 12 );
        }
        }
    }
}

here is the full source for references.
To some of you this might not seem like a programming question but my question is:
Is it possible to perform a lattice attack on this equation because someone suggested it but i do not know how to construct it.
Thank you

Solve it for 2^n for some n <32 first, then increase n 'til you get to 32.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4953266/14578
